# bootstrap switch getting value on change

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-switch

I am using bootstrap switch for setting value to NO when its OFF and Yes when its ON,

in HTML,

```
<input type="checkbox" id="limit" class="make-switch" data-on="success" data-on-color="success" data-off-color="danger" data-size="small">
```

in JS

```
    $("#limit").bootstrapSwitch();
    $('#limit').on( 'switchChange',function () {
    if ($("#limit").bootstrapSwitch('state') === true)
    {
        console.log('On');
    }
    else {
        console.log('Off');
    }
});
```

When i change switch i could not get any output on log,

What is wrong? and how can we get value of input field with bootstrap switch?

Thanks,

Comment: may this can be helpful to you https://vsn4ik.github.io/bootstrap-checkbox/     or  http://www.bootstraptoggle.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `switchChange` use the following event :

```
$('#limit').on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch',function (e,data) {
    //.......
});
```